# Excel- averaging subsequent cells using first unused cell in column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Good morning,

I need this output to be on a separate sheet, but essentially the problem I am trying to solve can be explained as follows.

I am trying to figure out how to average cells in a column with the following format:

In `B2` on Sheet2, I would like the `average(Sheet1!a2:a5)`, in `B3` the, `average(Sheet1!a6:a9)`, in `B4`, (Sheet1!a10:a13), etc.

I might have made this far more complicated than necessary, but my idea was to use the Offset function as follows:

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET(Sheet1!$a$2, 4*(ROW()-ROW(Sheet1!$a$2)), 0, 4, 1))`

Which worked! However, I then need another column to show different data, shown below:

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET(Sheet1!$a$118, 4*(ROW()-ROW(Sheet1!$a$118)), 0, 4, 1))`

Which gives me a reference error. Can anyone help me to understand why this isn't working? An easy solution would be appreciated, but an explanation of why would be especially great!!

Answer (score 0):

Right, so we will use a different formula for your first one -

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,1+4*(ROW()-ROW($B$1))):INDEX(A:A,4*(ROW()-ROW($B$1)+1)))
```

What this does is creates an array for the average to work on. It does this by finding the current row, subtracting the reference row, adding one and multiplying 4, for each side of the range. Use evaluate formula to see it in action.

Say you wanted to do this again, but starting at A118, which is what I think you're asking

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A118:A999,1+4*(ROW()-ROW($B$118))):INDEX(A118:A999,4*(ROW()-ROW($B$118)+1)))
```

Now, this requires you to do your work on row 118, but say you want to just start a new column back at row 1 -

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A118:A999,1+4*(ROW()-ROW($B$1))):INDEX(A118:A999,4*(ROW()-ROW($B$1)+1)))
```

Just like the first one.